# Monte Carlo integration and reweighting

Tags: monte-carlo, numerical-integration

I have to find the expectation of a particular function, $f(x)$ with respect to a gamma distribution $Ga(a_k,b_k)$. However, at each iteration $k$, the gamma parameters $a_k,b_k$ change.

Suppose $x^{(k)}_i$ are the samples that are generated from $Ga(a_k,b_k)$. Thus, $$E(f(x))_{Ga(a_k,b_k)}\approx \frac{1}{N}\sum_i f(x^{(k)}_i)$$

The question is can I somehow reweight $x^{(0)}_i$'s such that I don't have to keep re-sampling from a Gamma distribution which seems to be computationally expensive (considering how many times I do this calculation). $f(x)$ does not change.

Aside: Incase it helps my function $f(x)=-\sqrt{x^2+c^2}+c\log(\sqrt{x^2+c^2}+c)$

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but are you suggesting using the previously generated samples as the proposal distribution and comparing it against the pdf of the current distribution. I can understand that this will create samples for the new distribution but you will lose samples as some of them are discarded right? Will be a bigger issue when the two PDFs are wildly different. I was hoping for some sort of transformation actually.

Comment: importance sampling does not discard anything but uses the ratio of the densities.